# Как быстро делать скриншоты вне Activity?

Tags: java, android

Я ищю способ как можно быстро делать скриншоты вне activity приложения, желательно получить эти скриншоты в bitmap.
Единсвтенный способ, который я нашел - это делать скриншоты с помощью утилиты `screencap`:

```
/system/bin/screencap -p /storage/emulated/0/screenshot.png
```

Этот способ мне не подходит, так как он слишком медленный (около секунды на один скриншот).

Есть ли альтернативный способ, который будет работать быстрей?

Comment: Насколько нужно быстро делать скриншоты? Если нужно очень быстро, то подойдет ли вам запись экрана с помощью `adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/video.mp4` и далее выгрузка из видеопотока необходимых кадров?

Answer (score 1):

Если есть возможность использовать `adb` и `ffmpeg`, то можно сначала записать видео, потом разбить видео на необходимое количество кадров.

Записываем 1 секунду видео с экрана:

```bash
timeout 1 adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/record.mp4
```

Скачиваем видео:

```bash
adb pull /sdcard/record.mp4
```

Извлекаем кадры из видео с частотой 24 кадра в секунду:

```bash
ffmpeg -i record.mp4 -r 24 output_%d.png
```